# devise, when trying to change a password WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

with rails 3 + devise, I want a user to be able to change their password:

here's is the log output:

```
Started POST "/settings/password/update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-11 11:37:05 -0700
  Processing by SettingsController#password_update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QBZP/h0Xg1SOBWh0+JwzFRyC8X7pE50mx1CgeS6+iNY=", "user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password
  AREL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = '$2a$10$cjq9eWB41aqeukarMzyciO4adXB3g.gCSwP6OouV0HT9HZI3IVIa6', "updated_at" = '2011-08-11 18:37:06.326258' WHERE "users"."id" = 3
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  SQL (25.7ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/settings/account
Completed 302 Found in 556ms
```

Here is the controller method for password_update:

```
  def password_update

    @user = current_user

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = 'Password Updated'
      redirect_to '/settings/account'
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Error'
      redirect_to '/settings/password'
    end

  end
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm not trying to set current_password but according to devise you need to pass that to update the password, right? Thanks

Comment: Strange thing is it is updating the password but then signing the user out after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `attr_accessible :current_password` to your user model.

Comment: I get `unknown attribute: current_password` when I try this.

Comment: Me too. `:current_password` is not an attribute of the User object.

Comment: Then you may have to add `attr_accessor :current_password` to your model.  Also these links may help: [1](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) and [2](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1620)

Comment: for anyone who has mild brain damage like me, and couldn't deduce this from the above comments, know that you need BOTH `attr_accessible :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, etc...` AND `attr_accessor :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to override update_without_password method on User model

```
def update_without_password(params={})
  params.delete(:current_password)
  super(params)
end
```